# Centos 7 - pdftex.def not found

Tags: graphics, errors, mac, linux

I am trying to run a file using the following template (link is near the bottom of the page) https://www.ametsoc.org/ams/index.cfm/publications/authors/journal-and-bams-authors/latex-author-info/

However, the file runs fine on Mac but breaks on Centos 7

```
(File `pdftex.def' not found. ...ed{ver@\Gin@driver}{\input{\Gin@driver}}{})
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What does `kpsewhich pdftex.def` return in the CentOS?

Comment: depending on which tex distribution you have you may want to update `graphics-def` via tlmgr or your linux package manager